# I found a redis key is empty ,it is a list and has 102360 items

Tags: redis

I want to count redis big key,so I did this  redis-cli  --bigkeys， but I found a key is empty ,it is a list but there are 102360 items
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFfZq.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The empty string is a valid name for a key in Redis. You can access it like so:

```
redis-cli> TYPE ""
list
```